# Trainin, saving and importing a Libtorch Neural Network in C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, pytorch, neural-network, libtorch

I'm starting to get into neural networks in C++ using libtorch. I've created a simple game and trained a neural network with the Q learning method. I trained the network in a program, and now that I have a trained model I want to use it in the graphical version of the game so I can see what the model can do. I saved the model to a model.pt file as follows ([reference to this forum question](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/libtorch-how-to-save-model-in-mnist-cpp-example/34234)):

```
string model_path = "model.pt";
torch::serialize::OutputArchive output_archive;
qNetwork.save(output_archive);
output_archive.save_to(model_path);
```

It generates a `model.pt` file. Now I'm having trouble importing the model to the other program (which runs an SDL2 graphic version of the game). I've figured out how to properly import libtorch to that file, the problem is I don't know how to use the already trained model. I tried what [this article](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html) suggests:

```
torch::jit::script::Module module;
  try {
    // Deserialize the ScriptModule from a file using torch::jit::load().
    module = torch::jit::load(argv[1]);
  }
  catch (const c10::Error& e) {
    std::cerr << "error loading the model\n";
    return -1;
  }
```

For reference this is the Torch module:

```
class QNetwork : public torch::nn::Module {
private:
    torch::nn::Linear layer1{nullptr};
    torch::nn::Linear layer2{nullptr};
    torch::nn::Linear outputLayer{nullptr};
public:
    QNetwork(int inputSize, int outputSize) {
        layer1 = register_module("layer1", torch::nn::Linear(inputSize, 64));
        layer2 = register_module("layer2", torch::nn::Linear(64, 64));
        outputLayer = register_module("outputLayer", torch::nn::Linear(64, outputSize));
    }

    torch::Tensor forward(torch::Tensor x) {
        x = torch::relu(layer1->forward(x));
        x = torch::relu(layer2->forward(x));
        x = outputLayer->forward(x);
        return x;
    }
 };
```

How to resolve this issue?